# Embed ruby code inside view with HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

For example, I have such line:

```
<tr class="<%= cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
```

How I can translate it into HAML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%tr{ class: cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') }
```

*Response to comments, which is a separate question:*

This is your source, from your pastie:

```
%tr{:class => cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}
  %th
  - @books.each do |book|
    %tr
```

The above applies `cycle` to the *outer-most* table row, not each individual book's row:

```
%tr
  %th
  - @books.each do |book|
    %tr{ class: cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') }
```

Comment: yeap, I tried it, but it's not work for me. What I do wrong? http://www.pastie.org/3084886

Comment: @TiSer Hmm; how does it render?

Comment: @TiSer What does the HTML look like when you view the source?

Comment: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8978/screenshot2lk.png
and in HTML code I can see, that class from cycle has only the first TR: <tr class='list_line_odd'>

Comment: @TiSer That is not the rendered source, which can be cut-and-paste into your question. (Just the relevant parts, and only enough to show a cycle or two.)